# How do I Extract the First character of a symbol in scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I want it to extract all the words that have a letter e in them.
eg.

```
(ewords '(i e ee o oo)) -> '(e ee)
```

Berkeley's 61a lecture uses (first 'word) to extract the first character of the word. However DrScheme screams at me when I try to do that. How do take the first character of the word? like

```
(first 'word)->'w.
```

Comment: Berkeley's 61A does not use a standard version of Scheme; they add a little more support in the form of the Simply Scheme library.  See: http://planet.plt-scheme.org/package-source/dyoo/simply-scheme.plt/2/1/planet-docs/manual/index.html, which provides this support for Racket.

Comment: I ended up searching this question because I'm going through MIT 6.001 lectures (SICP), I built the pattern matcher in Lecture 4, now they're returning to it in Lecture 8 for implementing a Prolog-like language, but it would be nice to replace the expressions like (? y) that I'm using for matching variables with symbols like ?y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to convert it to a string explicitly:

```
(first (symbol->string 'word)) -> "w"
```

(I'm not sure off the top of my head whether `first` operates on strings.  You can use `string->list` to convert to a list and then take the `first` if it doesn't.)

EDIT:  It might be easier to pass around strings instead of symbols in the first place -- to designate a string, use double quotes (e.g. `(ewords '("i" "e" "ee" "o" "oo"))`.)  I don't know if this is your intent, but since you're learning, I thought I should mention the distinction.

Comment: Hmm using strings sounds good but i really wanted to use symbols. thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, the string->list is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Symbols are primarily meant to be atomic values, i.e., they are not usually taken apart and examined. If you really want to do it you must first do some type conversions:

```
    ; #\a -> a
    (define (char->symbol chr)
      (string->symbol (list->string (list chr))))

    ; abc -> (a b c)
    (define (symbol->list sym)
      (map char->symbol 
           (string->list (symbol->string sym))))
```

You can now use `first`:

```
    > (first (symbol->list 'word))
    w
```

Comment: This isn't true at all. Only one use of quoting among very many is for producing atomic enum-like values. It might be the first use of quoting beginners learn about, but it is far from the most common or powerful. A much more significant use of quoting is for enabling metalinguistic abstraction. Another use, unquote-splicing, is so popular Racket built out quasiquoting to make it easier. The significance of symbols is that they go through the reader atomically, rather than being evaluated as expressions. Once passed to a procedure it is ordinary to process them further.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, what is the data definition for a "word"?

Is it a sequence of characters (aka a string)? Is it a list of characters? A list of strings? A list of symbols?

Here is a function that meets your criteria, but as you can see, it is convoluted and I wonder if it is what you really want:

```
; symbol->list-of-symbols : symbol -> (ListOf symbol)
; To destructure a symbol into a list of its constituent parts
(define (symbol->list-of-symbols sym)
  (map (lambda (s) (string->symbol (string s))) 
       (string->list (symbol->string sym))))
```