# Scheme- How to code a deck of cards with values

Tags: scheme, racket

I am new to Scheme (AKA DrRacket) and was wondering how i would go about to creating a deck of cards with values attached to it. e.g., 1H -> 0.5 and so forth.

Any replies would be appreciated, many thanks!

Comment: That rather depends on how you're planning to use it. Data structures and algorithms go hand in hand.

Comment: There are any number of ways to represent this, and as @molbdnilo said, which would make the most sense would depend on what you mean to do with it. It might also depend on whether you need to use a specific dialect of Scheme or Racket, as  DrRacket supports several and each has somewhat different methods for representing data.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (make-card rank suit)
  (word rank (first suit)))


(make-card 7 'spades)

7s
```

This piece of data abstraction code should work for scheme but not sure for drracket as drracket doesn't has word and first primitives. At least it can give you an idea. Primitive first takes suit's first letter and word primitive joins rank of the card and the first letter of the suit. This is a constructor code which is you can make a abstract data type with this and you need a selectors also to select rank and suit of the card.

Comment: [Scheme](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-21.html#node_index_start) doesn't have `first` or `word` as primitives either.

Comment: @Sylwester I have seen these on cs61a so I thought they're primitives but you're right here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942040/how-do-i-extract-the-first-character-of-a-symbol-in-scheme dyoo commented that "Berkeley's 61A does not use a standard version of Scheme"